# How to download zip files from a website using Talend?

Tags: talend

I want to download a zip file from this website, unzip it and then show it into an excel file.
http://www.belgianfootball.be/nl/downloads-competities

With which component can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tHTTRequest component. 
https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/14.11+tHttpRequest

Here you can find a nice guide:
https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-thttprequest-component.html